# EJB security misunderstanding

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I don't understand how EJB security works.

I have RESTful web-service with BASIC authentication. It looks like

```
@javax.ws.rs.core.Context javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext sc;

@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test() throws Exception {    
  Principal principal = sc.getUserPrincipal();    
  MyEJBLocal myEjb = (MyEJBLocal) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJBLocal");
  return myEjb.test();    
}
```

`sc.getUserPrincipal()` returns here authenticated user.

And I have EJB and local interface

```
@Local
public interface MyEJBLocal {
  public String test() throws Exception;
}  

@Stateless
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBLocal {
  @Resource javax.ejb.SessionContext ctx;

  public String test() throws Exception {
    java.security.Principal principal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
    ....
  }
}
```

here `ctx.getCallerPrincipal()` returns anonymous. I don't understand how principal in SessionContext setted. Should I make some extra authentication? Why I have principal in SecurityContext and anonymous in SessionContext?

**UPD**: I create my own SecurityContext and set it in `filter(ContainerRequest request)` of `ContainerRequestFilter` as `request.setSecurityContext()`. I've find out that's the reason why in SessionContext I haven't authenticated user. How can I make something similar to own SecurityContext for EJB?

Comment: Your code works fine in WAS 8.5.5 (assuming that you have security constraint correctly configured in `web.xml` and enabled security in server). What kind of application server are you using? Looks like issue in server configuration.

Comment: Is your EJB in separate module/application or inside war? Can you add `web.xml` and `ejb-jar.xml` if you have them? Maybe Weblogic doesn't propagate user, if EJB is not protected. Try to add `@RolesAllowed("yourRole")` to your `MyEJB` class.

Comment: You should not create security context by yourself, if you want to use container managed authentication/authorization. Add correct security constraint to your web.xml and then container will perform authentication and will create security context. Then this context will be correctly passed to your EJB.